# Is ((f f) (g g)) reduced differently in AOR and NOR?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus, reduction

How is ((f f) (g g)) reduced in both applicative order reduction and normal order reduction? do both reduce the statement in the same way?

Comment: do you mean `(λf.f f) (λg.g g)` or `(f f) (g g)`?

Comment: f should be an abstract lambda function like `(λf.f)`, so this example would be `(λf.f)(λf.f) ((λg.g) (λg.g))`

Answer (score 0):

Assume "reduce" means "Beta-Reduct".
I'm not going to be rigorous and introduice formals definitions, because of this is not the question.
Before, i need to clarify some terms :

- A `beta-contraction` (writes `~>` here) means a single step of the evaluation.
  For example `(λx.λy.xy)(a)(b) ~> (λy.ay)(b) forall terms a, b`
- A `beta-reduction` (writes `=>` here) means a complete evaluation.
  For example `(λx.λy.xy)(a)(b) => ab forall atoms a, b`
- A term is in a `beta-normal form` if it's no contain redexes.
  For example `λx.x` **is** a `beta-normal form`, but `(λx.x)y` **has** a `beta-normal form` (`y`) iff `y` **has** a `beta-normal form`.
  An other important point : A term `A` has a unique `beta-normal form` regardless wich strategy we apply to reduce A.
- Two terms are `beta-equals` (writes `==` here) if their `beta-normal forms` are `alpha-equivalent`
  For example `(λx.λy.xy)(a)(b) == (λy.ay)(b)`

In the case of the `AOR strategy`, to reduce a term `A`, we `beta-contract` the **rightmost innermost** redex until we get a `beta-normal form`.
More visually :

> `>> (λx.x)((λy.y)((λz.z)a))`
> `~> (λx.x)((λy.y)a)`
> `~> (λx.x)a`
> `~> a`

In the case of the `NOR strategy`, to reduce a term `A`, we `beta-contract` the **leftmost outermost** redex until we get a `beta-normal form`
More visually :

> `>> (λx.x)((λy.y)((λz.z)a))`
> `~> (λy.y)((λz.z)a)`
> `~> (λz.z)a`
> `~> a`

So, in your case, with `f f => A`, `g g => B`
**AOR** :

> `>> (f f)(g g)`
> `~> (f f)B`
> `~> AB`

**NOR** :

> `>> (f f)(g g)`
> `~> A(g g)`
> `~> AB`

It's not very rigorous, but the idea is clear.
And, of course, `(f f)(g g) == (f f)(g g)`